# Can I only add autocomplete 'address' and 'postcode' to a form?

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I have a customer form with autocomplete address option. I actually Only need the Address and postcode adding to the form, so how do I filter out the rest; town, city, district etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!!

Autocomplete Textbox using jQuery, PHP and MySQL [Click](https://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/)